# ddply summarise string operation

Tags: r, plyr

I am using `ddply` right now. It's very easy to deal with numbers. Such as take the mean or standard deviation of the subgroup.

But I have difficulty dealing with strings. I would like to combine the strings in the same column in each subgroup, but I could not do it. I tried `cbind` `paste`, etc. Anyone can offer some help?

Comment: Without a concrete, reproducible example, no, we probably can't offer much help.

Comment: Please produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to get help...

Answer (score 8):

Add `collapse=""` to your paste statement

```
ddply(mtcars, .(carb), summarize, cyl_concatenated = paste(cyl, collapse = ""))
#  carb cyl_concatenated
#1    1          4664444
#2    2       8444888444
#3    3              888
#4    4       6686688888
#5    6                6
#6    8                8
```

Answer (score 5):

I see Dason has an approach. I would rather keeps separate things separate and would suggest:

```
 ddply(mtcars, .(carb), summarize, cyl_list = list(as.character(cyl)))
#-----------
  carb                     cyl_list
1    1          4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4
2    2 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4
3    3                      8, 8, 8
4    4 6, 6, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
5    6                            6
6    8                            8
```

You could also modify Dason's to use collapse=", " which would look the same as above but would have a different structure. With `list()` you need to convert to character when using that example, or you get the integer coding of the factor variable.